# Why do some pandas methods require a list and not take tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

I was surprised to find that in pandas, if you want to remove columns by name,

`my_dataframe.drop(['column_name_one','column_name_two','column_name_three'])`

works, but

`my_dataframe.drop(('column_name_one','column_name_two','column_name_three'))`

does not. Is there a technical reason, or a philosophical rationale, for this design decision?

Comment: *"A tuple will be used as a single label and not treated as a list-like."* https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop A tuple is a valid column name in Pandas, so if tuples were accepted as *sequences* of column names in functions like this, you'd run into ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks! Why did you post that as a comment rather than an answer? It's a good answer.

Comment: Curious about the downvote. Is this an "RTFM" downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [method documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) states that:

> A tuple will be used as a single label and not treated as a list-like.

What's driving these semantics is that:

1. The method accepts a single label as valid, i.e. you can do `df.drop('foo')` instead of `df.drop(['foo'])`
2. A tuple is a valid column name in Pandas.

So in the light of those facts, if a tuple could be interpreted as a sequence of labels, then `df.drop(('foo', 'bar'))` would be ambiguous: is it trying to remove the one column `('foo', 'bar')`, or the two columns `'foo'` and `'bar'`?

Therefore we end up with the behaviour you observe, where tuples and lists are treated non-equivalently.

Comment: A good reminder for API designers thinking “oh it’ll be less confusing if we just accept either type and convert it automatically” that syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon.